# DXA Context Expressions using custom claims

Tags: dxa, context-engine

We are currently looking into DXA and Target Groups/Context Expressions. Using the [Context Expressions module](https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/sdl-dxa-context-expressions-module/739/) we can filter certain Component Presentations to show/not show, depending on the specified Target Group.

We can create these Target Groups, and make use of the default Context Service variables, such as browser version, os, ..., using the powershell script provided with the Context Expressions module.

```
.\set-context-expression.ps1 -cmsUrl http://localhost -targetGroupId tcm:123-456-256 -contextExpression "browser.vendor == 'Google'"
```

I was wondering if we can use any custom properties (e.g. a custom ADF claim) in the contextExpression, eg `-contextExpression "my.custom.property == 'xxx'"`.

I did notice that in the Context microservice configuration, you can map such properties to ADF claims, using a translator in the `cwd_engine_conf.xml` of the Context microservice, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have an explanation how to get this to work?